# Avoiding (ambiguous call to overloaded function)

Tags: c++

Good morning, I was solving a problem on a different site and i had to make an operation which takes a number, divides it by another and then output an integer no matter what the output is so i made the formula like so:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
 int n,y=0;
 double x=0.0;
 cin >> n;

if(n%100 == 0){
    y= n%100;
    x+= floor(n/100);
    if(y%20 == 0){
        x += floor(y/20);
        y= y%20;
        if(y%10 == 0){
           x+= floor(y/10);
           y= y%10;
            if(y%5 == 0){
                x += floor(y/5);
                y= y%5;
                if(y%1 == 0)
                x+= floor(y/1);
            }
        }
    }
}
cout >> x;
}
```

I end up getting the error:

```
program.cpp(12) : error C2668: 'floor' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
```

How can i avoid such error when making likewise programs?

Comment: Works for me, with the `cout >> x` fixed, that is. Perhaps `using namespace std;`  is making `std::floor` from `<cmath>` clash with `floor` from `<math.h>`. I couldn't do that in Visual Studio however even when including both of those headers. Still, you might want to try removing `using namespace std;`.

Comment: Also, repeatedly assigning zero to `y` (you're consistently doing `if (e == 0) {... y = e;...}`) doesn't seem very useful.

Comment: @molbdnilo i'm repeatedly assigning the number to y because in case the input is large i want it to divide it into pieces such as (5532 --> 32 --> 2 --> 0) .. the point is to take every part and get a value out of each ... is there a better way to do so?

Comment: @Eloi If `y % x` is `0`, which it is inside every conditional, `y = y % x` is the same as `y = 0`, and `0 % x` is always `0`. All you're doing is computing `n/100` and then adding zero to it.

Comment: I believe I left a comment about the pointlessness of applying `floor` to an integer, but it seems to have been deleted. If `x` is an integer, `floor(x)` has the same effect as `static_cast<double>(x)`, and all your divisions produce `int`s.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include cmath to use the floor function. The cmath library declares a set of functions to compute common mathematical operations and transformations:

```
#include <cmath>
```

Source: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/floor/

Also, change the bottom line to `cout << x;`

Comment: I tried doing so when i read your answer.. it still print out the same error, what should i change the bottom line to?

Comment: Did you change the `x` and `y` to doubles? You should change the bottom line from `cout >> x` to `cout << x`.

Comment: i did all the but what the error still comes out in addition to telling me that i can't use the remainder process to float variables